# More code in HTML or CSS

Tags: html, css

Which is the proper way? Putting more classes in a div or just using a parent div to give the same class to the children within.

Ex. All in HTML file:

```
<p class="pt-1 fontsize20 text-uppercase bg-black"> text here </p>
```

Ex. All in CSS file:

```
<div class="parent">
    <p> text here </p>
    <p> text here </p>
    <p> text here </p>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.parent p {
  padding-top:10px;font-size:20px;text-transform:uppercase;background:#000;
}
```

Sorry first post, don't know how to put code in

Comment: It is confusing to read your post without proper HTML code. For example, use `<p>text here</p>` and not `"p" text here "p"`.

Answer (score 3):

Part of good programming technique is keeping things DRY (Do Not Repeat yourself).

There are two problems with your first method:

1. It is not DRY - meaning you will have to repeat that for every paragraph you want it applied to.
2. You are specifying what it should look like in the class names. Classnames should never represent appearance. For instance you are using the `fontsize20` as a class name. That represents the appearance of size 20. If you decide later that you want the font size to be 25, you could change your CSS to 25, but your class name would still say fontsize20. This would be confusing to anyone looking at your code. Instead use class names that are descriptive of the data it contains, not the style it should look like. Ex. `class="customer_data"` would be a much better class name.

Answer (score -1):

There is no correct way between the 2 ways. Go with whatever the project is using already or pick one of the 2 if there's no currently established method.

To put code in click the {} button or the snippet button to the right of it. Or use 4 spaces to indent and it'll show up in a code block. You can also use tick marks to indicate code like this: `display: block;`

[image]

Comment: Click where on what button? There is no reference to any IDE in the question.

Comment: I believe he was talking about how to put code into Stack Overflow when you ask a question.

Comment: Nowhere do I see that reference. Except the vague last sentence .. You might be right.. :-) ..